# Lazy log message evaluation in java

Tags: java, lambda

In some instances, I am interested in deferring the creation of the log message, so it won't be created in the case the log level is not sufficient.

I do it by passing a callback to a logging function, which is called if the logging level is sufficient.

The problem is I can't pass a variable which is not effectively final, because of closure limitations Java has.

What is a cleaner way to do it?

Running code: http://tpcg.io/IspNlN

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class StackOverflow
{
    private static final int LOG_LEVEL=2;
    private static final int TRACE_LEVEL=0;

    private static void trace(Supplier<String> messageCallback){
        if(TRACE_LEVEL>LOG_LEVEL) return;
        System.out.println(messageCallback.get());          
    }

    private static void foo(){      
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            doSomething();
            int finalI=i; //I need it because of "Local variable parameterIndex defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final"
            trace(()->"FLOW-1: "+getHugeString()+" for i:"+finalI);
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        foo();
    }

    private static  void doSomething(){
        //some operation
    }

    private static String getHugeString(){          
        return "A huge string that took much time to create";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the cleanest way imho. It's not really a limitation, but a deliberate restriction that avoids having to wonder what `i` will be when you execute the callback after changing `i`. This way, any variable you capture can only have 1 value.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use a logging framework?

Comment: @David I posted a minimal working example. Do you know a logging framework which solves this issue? log4j 2 accepts functional interfaces, which pose the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three options mentioned in order of preference.

Option 1

Use a proper logging library.

Option 2 as pointed by @Glains

```
private static boolean isTraceEnabled()
{
    return TRACE_LEVEL <= LOG_LEVEL;
}

private static void trace(String msg)
{
    if (isTraceEnabled())
    {
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
}

private static void foo()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        doSomething();
        if (isTraceEnabled())
        {
            trace("FLOW-1: " + getHugeString() + " for i:" + i);
        }
    }
}
```

Option 3 use message format as in jdk logger.

```
private static void trace(String format, Object... values)
{
    if (TRACE_LEVEL > LOG_LEVEL)
    {
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
    {
        Object value = values[i];
        if (value instanceof Supplier)
        {
            values[i] = ((Supplier) value).get();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(new MessageFormat(format).format(values));
}
```

invocation like

```
trace("FLOW-1: {0} for i: {1}", (Supplier) (StackOverflow::getHugeString), i);
```

Comment: I liked the 3rd one. It gives you an option to easily tweak the evaluation type of your string provider. The casting is a bit nasty but it seems to me much less evil than 'if' or dummy variables. Why is it less preferable in your opinion?

Comment: a proper logging library is the best because it takes care of many more issues, dynamic logging level changes, async logging, log rollovers etc. For most of your logging calls, you would not need a delayed execution using supplier, so option 3 is really coding for the corner case. For this extreme corner case one "if check" like option 2 should not be an issue. Just my opinion.

Comment: Sure, in real life a logging framework is a must. This solution may work as well as a wrapper for a call to a logging framework.

Answer (score 0):

Common logging frameworks offer methods like `isDebugEnabled` or `isInfoEnabled` to guard exactly against that case where Strings may take a longer time to be created.

```
if(LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
    LOG.debug("Some objects toString method called: {}", someObject.toString());
}
```

Besides that, your method also works, but has the limitations that you pointed out already.